# How to pass payload using HttpOutboundAdapter in Spring-Integration

Tags: https, spring-integration, dsl

We are trying to pass a payload to a POST call that is being made using HttpOutboundGateway. A file is read and the content is stored in the channel. In order to retrieve the content of the channel, we are setting the extractPayload to true. We are using Spring-Integration along with DSL and not the XML approach. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("FileContentChannel")
                .channel("FileContentChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("xxx", "xxx")
                        .header("xxx", "xxx"))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://payment/gateway")
                        .charset("UTF-8")
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .extractPayload(true)
                        .mappedRequestHeaders("pay*")
                        .headerMapper(headerMapper())
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("paymentResponseChannel"))
                .get();
```

Error log :

```
2016-10-26 16:34:22.343 ERROR 1584 --- [ask-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://payment/gateway]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:409)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:516)
at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382)
... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.handle()` is for Service Activator EI pattern. And exactly its responsibility to deliver `payload` from the `input` channel to the target service. In your case it is `RestTemplate` underneath and an HTTP body is built from the `payload`.

Your configuration looks fully correct. I don't understand where is the problem...

**EDIT**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

Not, sure what makes you think that there is something wrong with `payload`. Looks like you are missing some HTTP header or use them with wrong value.

You should consult with the server to determine what should be done else.
There is no any clue in your StackTrace that there is something wrong with payload.

OTOH, since we get  `404 Not Found` that means that the `payload` is passed from the channel to the `Http.outboundGateway()`.

Comment: Thats right. I have a channel which returns the file content as payload when when printed prints just fine. But when using the **extractPayload** method, I dont think the payload gets passed on from the channel to the API call.

Comment: Please, take a look into an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: I am sure that its the payload because I have tested the API on a standalone rest client and also with other GET calls where the only difference being that there is no payload associated to it and that works fine. Is there any other method that can be used to pass the payload explicitly to HttpOutboundGateway ?

Comment: Well, try to put break point into the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage()` and see what's going on with the `requestMessage`. Exactly that one contains a desired `payload`. Plus you can switch on DEBUG log level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and also observe how your `payload` is traveling. Since you have a response from the server that means that the `payload` (`requestMessage`) has reached `HttpOutboundGateway`. You `GET` test doesn't have anything common with the `POST` here...